# Why is Python consistently struggling to keep up with constant generation of asyncio tasks?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a Python project with a server that distributes work to one or more clients. Each client is given a number of assignments which contain parameters for querying a target API. This includes a maximum number of requests per second they can make with a given API key. The clients process the response and send the results back to the server to store into a database.

Both the server and clients use [Tornado](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/) for asynchronous networking. My [initial implementation](https://github.com/kamakazikamikaze/wotplayertrackerv2/blob/master/trackerv2/client/client.py#L89) for the clients relied on the [`PeriodicCallback`](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#tornado.ioloop.PeriodicCallback) to ensure that n-number of calls to the API would occur. I thought that this was working properly as my tests would last 1-2 minutes.

I added some telemetry to collect statistics on performance and noticed that the clients were actually having issues after almost exactly 2 minutes of runtime. I had set the API requests to 20 per second (the maximum allowed by the API itself) which the clients could reliably hit. However, after 2 minutes performance would fluctuate between 12 and 18 requests per second. The number of active tasks steadily increased until it hit the maximum amount of active assignments (100) given from the server and the HTTP request time to the API was reported by Tornado to go from 0.2-0.5 seconds to 6-10 seconds. Performance is steady if I only do 14 requests per second. Anything higher than 15 requests will experience issues 2-3 minutes after starting. [Logs can be seen here](https://gist.github.com/kamakazikamikaze/efb1a85bedb827ac5a73bc1e5604eb4b). Notice how the column of "Active Queries" is steady until 01:19:26. I've truncated the log to demonstrate

I believed the issue was the use of a single process on the client to handle both communication to the server and the API. [I proceeded to split the primary process](https://github.com/kamakazikamikaze/wotplayertrackerv2/blob/client-perf/trackerv2/client/client.py) into several different processes. One handles all communication to the server, one (or more) handles queries to the API, another processes API responses into a flattened class, and finally a multiprocessing Manager for Queues. The performance issues were still present.

I thought that, perhaps, Tornado was the bottleneck and decided to refactor. I chose [`aiohttp` and `uvloop`](https://github.com/kamakazikamikaze/wotplayertrackerv2/blob/client-aiohttp/trackerv2/client/client.py). I split the primary process in a similar manner to that in the previous attempt. Unfortunately, performance issues are unchanged.

I took both refactors and enabled them to split work into several querying processes. However, no matter how much you split the work, you still encounter problems after 2-3 minutes.

---

I am using both Python 3.7 and 3.8 on MacOS and Linux.

At this point, it does not appear to be a limitation of a single package. I've thought about the following:

- Python's `asyncio` library cannot handle more than 15 coroutines/tasks being generated per second

I doubt that this is true given that different libraries claim to be able to handle several thousand messages per second simultaneously. Also, we can hit 20 requests per second just fine at the start with very consistent results.

- The API is unable to handle more than 15 requests from a single client IP

This is unlikely as I am not the only user of the API and I can request 20 times per second fairly consistently over an extended period of time if I [over-subscribe processes to query from the API](https://github.com/kamakazikamikaze/wotcbattlecounter/blob/master/src/collect.py#L355).

- There is a system configuration causing the limitation

I've tried both MacOS and Debian which yield the same results. It's possible that's it a *nix problem.

- Variations in responses cause a backlog which grows linearly until it cannot be tackled fast enough

Sometimes responses from the API grow and shrink between 0.2 and 1.2 seconds. The number of active tasks returned by `asyncio.all_tasks` remains consistent in the telemetry data. If this were true, we wouldn't be consistently encountering the issue at the same time every time.

- We're overtaxing the hardware with the number of tasks generated per second and causing thermal throttling

Although CPU temperatures spike, neither MacOS nor Linux report any thermal throttling in the logs. We are not hitting more than 80% CPU utilization on a single core.

---

At this point, I'm not sure what's causing it and have considered refactoring the clients into a different language (perhaps C++ with Boost libraries). Before I dive into something so foolish, I wanted to ask if I'm missing something simple.

Comment: It's really hard to tell what the problem is here, but you are quite correct in assuming that asyncio is designed to handle your use case. Since you see the same problem on both MacOS and Debian, it's most likely an issue with your code (more likely), or a bug in asyncio (less likely, but still quite possible). Can you narrow down the issue to create a small test program that reproduces this behavior? Another option is to use `strace` to monitor what the process is doing when it slows down.

Comment: Also, you can test whether the event loop itself is getting bogged down by adding a heartbeat task which just prints stuff to the log in regular intervals.

Comment: I've captured an `strace` log with verbose debugging and all children included. It's very much over my head in terms of what's being said. I have not created a heartbeat yet but in my attempts to capture meaningful `strace` output I did notice that the client software logs spawning 3-7 querying tasks before the API responds, causing a bit of a backlog when this issue shows up in the telemetry. After that, the client begins to get bogged down. It's odd though as the client handles falling behind just fine up until the 2-minute threshold. It never catches back up afterwards.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it may be the API. The server I've coded gives out work parameters that begin at a specific number and increase sequentially. Whenever I restart the test, it goes back to that number. I did a test run where I cancelled the client but kept my work server running, then restarted the client. Immediately, I began to see the throttle. Looks like the API is struggling.

Comment: I've created a separate test case which cuts out the server-client model of my project and simply queries from the API, using a separate site as a benchmark. Asyncio can certainly handle 30-50 requests per second just fine. The API I'm targeting in my project does occasionally have hiccups but the test code can recover when it falls behind. So it's likely something in my project. No empirical evidence, but setting a long DNS cache (1 hr vs 10 sec default) seems to minimize hiccups. Perhaps aiodns is causing some errors later during runtime...? Too much going on to isolate it to just one cause.

Comment: Maybe aiodns, or some other part of the stack, is not fully async and uses `run_in_executor` internally, and starts to block when all threads are busy. Try raising the max number of threads in the executor used by the event loop and see if that makes s difference. (You can do that by creating a new executor with a larger max thread count, and installing it with loop.set_default_executor). Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Conclusion

Performance appears to vary wildly depending on time of day. It's likely to be the API.

## How this conclusion was made

I created a [new project](https://github.com/kamakazikamikaze/wot-api-stress/) to demonstrate the capabilities of `asyncio` and determine if it's the bottleneck. This project takes two websites, one to act as the baseline and the other is the target API, and runs through different methods of testing:

1. Spawn one process per core, pass a semaphore, and query up to n-times per second
2. Create a single event loop and create n-number of tasks per second
3. Create multiple processes with an event loop each to distribute the work, with each loop performing (n-number / processes) tasks per second

(Note that spawning processes is incredibly slow and often commented out unless using high-end desktop processors with 12 or more cores)

The baseline website would be queried up to 50 times per second. `asyncio` could complete 30 tasks per second reliably for an extended period, with each task completing their run in 0.01 to 0.02 seconds. Responses were very consistent.

The target website would be queried up to 20 times per second. Sometimes `asyncio` would struggle despite circumstances being identical (JSON handling, dumping response data to queue, returning immediately, no CPU-bound processing). However, results varied between tests and could not always be reproduced. Responses would be under 0.4 seconds initially but quickly increase to 4-10 seconds per request. 10-20 requests would return as complete per second.

As an alternative method, I chose a parent URI for the target website. This URI wouldn't have a large query to their database but instead be served back with a static JSON response. Responses bounced between 0.06 seconds to 2.5-4.5 seconds. However, 30-40 responses would be completed per second.

Splitting requests across processes with their own event loop would decrease response time in the upper-bound range by almost half, but still took more than one second each to complete.

The inability to reproduce consistent results every time from the target website would indicate that it's a performance issue on their end.